# How toPerform a left join in linq pad -

Tags: linq-to-sql, left-join, linqpad

How can I get linq pad to run my left join as show below?

```
var query = 
            from s in db.CDBLogsHeaders
                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.LogDateTime)
                    from sc in db.StyleColors
                        .Where(stylecolor => stylecolor.id == (int?)s.StyleColorID)
                        .DefaultIfEmpty()
                    from c in db.StyleHeaders
                        .Where(styleHeader => styleHeader.id == (int?)s.StyleHeaderID)
                        .DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new 
        {
            CDBLogsHeaderId = s.Id,
            Merchandiser = c.Merchandiser,
            Material = s.Material,
            Season = s.Season,
            LogsHeaderLogType = s.LogType,
            PushFromTo = s.PushFromTo,
            LinePlan = s.LinePlan,
            QuikRefNumber = s.QuikRefNumber,
            PLMOrigin = s.PLM_Origin,
            SeasonOriginal = c.SeasonOriginal,
            SeasonCurrent = c.SeasonCurrent,
            StyleHeaderId = c.Id,
            StyleCode = c.StyleCode,
            StyleColorsColorCode = sc.ColorCode
        };

    query.Dump();
```

The sql that linq pad creates runs perfectly in Management Studio but linq-pad doesn't display any rows and gives this error

> InvalidOperationException: The null value cannot be assigned to a
>   member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type.

How can I get linqpad to work so I can play with it?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128558/102937

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your anonymous type, make sure your ints are returning ints.

Change

```
StyleHeaderId = c.Id,
```

To

```
StyleHeaderId = (c.Id == null ? 0 : c.Id),
```